# "Fast Find" for views?

Tags: xpages

I realize I can filter a view on the first sorted column but is there a way to mimic the client "fast find" feature?   Basically a "fast forward" for a view.  Where the user would type all or part of the value in the first column then the view would be positioned to the appropriate document but with all other documents remaining in the view.

Comment: where do you want the user to type, is there a field in your first column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the startkey parameter for that and refreshing a panel that contains the entry field and the view. Caveat: that approach would generate a lot of chatter on the network and serverside. You might be better off using a Dojo grid and the [Dojo Search](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Search.html).